# GridLayoutManager same background for each row

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, grid-layout, gridlayoutmanager

I have been trying this project in [link](http://www.android-examples.com/android-recyclerview-with-gridview-gridlayoutmanager/). Everything is working fine. I got an output also. I would like to enhance it but I don't know what to do. I am having a background , I need to keep it as background for each row of gridlayoutmanager in recyclerview.
Please help me on this. and Thanks in advance

```
MainActivity.java
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

RecyclerView recyclerView;

Context context;

RecyclerView.Adapter recyclerView_Adapter;

RecyclerView.LayoutManager recyclerViewLayoutManager;

String[] numbers = {
        "one",
        "two",
        "three",
        "four",
        "five",
        "six",
        "seven",
        "eight",
        "nine",
        "ten",
        "eleven",

};


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    context = getApplicationContext();

    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view1);


    recyclerViewLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(context, 2);

    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(recyclerViewLayoutManager);

    recyclerView_Adapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(context,numbers);

    recyclerView.setAdapter(recyclerView_Adapter);

}
}

RecyclerViewAdapter.java
public class RecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.
Adapter<RecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder>{

String[] values;
Context context1;

public RecyclerViewAdapter(Context context2,String[] values2){

    values = values2;

    context1 = context2;
}

public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    public TextView textView;

    public ViewHolder(View v){

        super(v);

        textView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textview1);

    }
}

@Override
public RecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder 
onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType){

    View view1 = LayoutInflater.from(context1).inflate
 (R.layout.recycler_view_items,parent,false);

    ViewHolder viewHolder1 = new ViewHolder(view1);

    return viewHolder1;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder Vholder, int position){

    Vholder.textView.setText(values[position]);

    Vholder.textView.setBackgroundColor(Color.CYAN);

    Vholder.textView.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);

}

@Override
public int getItemCount(){

    return values.length;
}
}
```

Comment: share some more code - your background, your adapter, don't expect us to checkout a project form a link in the question in order to help you

Comment: so when you set the background on the recycler_view_items nothing happens ?

Comment: That background will be shown in each item but i need this background for each row.

Answer (score 0):

Easy Hack :
U can use LinearLayout manager instead of gridLayoutManager.
Then u can change item layout (layout for each item in adpater ie:recycler_view_items) to

something like this

```
<LinearLayout
 background: set it as ur image>
   <LinearLayout>
    // first item 
   </LinearLayout>

   <LinearLayout>
     //2nd item
   </LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout>
```

and change adapter to set values accordingly.
It requires changing layout and adapter codes.
This will work for u as u can set background for each row

(PS: Each row is now considered as a single item)

Comment: Thanks buddy but i need to use gridlayoutmanager because i am showing items in grid only .. In Grid view , i have show each row with same image..

Comment: grid layout will not help u achieve this .adapter uses each object separately to draw items. u will not get access to each row inside adapter

Comment: OK, Thank You Vicky :)